# Can (G)ARCH models be applied when their is no MA component in the mean equation, or can only ARCH be applied?

Tags: time-series, garch

My best mean equation was an AR(1) process (based on the Schwarz-Bayesian IC). I now want to model the conditional variance (having confirmed the volatility is not constant).

I just want to check whether the G in GARCH can be applied, or whether the ARCH will be all that is required given the mean equation does not having a MA component (and no lagged error term).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there is no reason to restrict the model for the conditional variance based on the model for the conditional mean. Thus you can have an ARCH or GARCH model for the conditional variance regardless of what model you have for the conditional mean (constant only, AR, MA, ARMA or something else).

You may select the model for the conditional variance based on how well it describes the data or how well it forecasts out of sample. You could select it based on theory as well. (I am not familiar with theories that imply concrete ARCH or GARCH models for the conditional variance -- unlike some macroeconomic models that imply certain ARIMA-type models for the conditional mean -- but that does not mean such models cannot not exist.)

Comment: It's a returns time series so I assume GARCH1,1 or ARCH1 will probably be sufficient and cheers!!

Comment: GARCH(1,1) is pretty standard, but asymmetric models such as GJR-GARCH could be useful, too. And the conditional distribution of standardized errors could be heavy-tailed such as Student(3) or so.

Comment: About using the student-t distribution, it means the excess kurtosis is dealt with but does it not also change the log-likelihood estimations? Not sure if I would know how this would affect the forecasts so I could not justify doing it although you're right in suggesting it

Comment: @BAMIR, Yes, the log-likelihood is different. If you are using a software package rather than coding the model estimation and prediction by hand, it will take care of all of that.

Comment: I have the unfortunate pleasure of doing it by hand. I also unfortunately cannot find the formula for an EGARCH estimation in Eviews, although assuming the mean in the model will just be sqrt(2/pi)?

Comment: I don't these details by heart, sorry.

Comment: I'm sorry to contact you via these comments, Richard, but if you could please help me in my most recent question, I would really appreciate it. Once again, sorry for using these comments to ask you.

Comment: @BAMIR, That's OK. But I have to apologize I cannot really help. That would involved delving a little deeper than I am prepared to at the moment. I hope you will understand. It is a pity there are so few users who answer GARCH questions here :/

Comment: No worries, thought I was stretching it to be fair